Why does order of the data matter for neural network?
Recently, I discovered the really weird behaviour of my an AI model. I wanted to build AI model that would try and guess the implicit functions based on the data I gave it. For example, the equation of the flower is:

And this is how I wrote it in the Numpy array:
K = 0.75
a = 9

def f(x):
    return x - 2 - 2*np.floor((x - 1)/2)

def r1(x):
    return abs(6 * f(a * K * x / 2 / np.pi)) - a/2
    
t = np.linspace(0, 17 * math.pi, 1000)
x = np.cos(t) * r1(t)
y = np.sin(t) * r1(t)

points = np.vstack((x, y)).T

After that, I tried to experiment a bit and allowed my AI to actually try and guess the shape of this flower! At first try, it actually got it written.
Here it is:

Well, I got a great example. After that, I tried to experiment and checked what would happen if I shuffled the point array, and I completely got devasting results!

And I couldn't explain why the order of cartesian coordinates mattered to the approximate flower implicit function. Can anyone explain it?
Here is the code for AI.
# Define the neural network model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, input_dim=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='linear'))

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

# Train the model
model.fit(points, points, epochs=100, batch_size=32)



Solved it, so actually problem was how i was drawing the actual result of the AI. Ai actually generalized it good but, since points were shuffled matplotlib just connected the points out of order and got weird results.

Shan't you repair / correct the claims " allowed my AI to actually try and guess the shape " and " Approximated Shape ", which neither actually happened? The correct text might be "How Matplotlib connected a given list of dots", might be not?

Actually, it's a plotting issue. The order in a plot matters while the one of a scatter don't :

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

shuffled_points = np.random.permutation(points)

plt.scatter(*points.T)          # in .scatter()-method POINT-s are depicted
plt.scatter(*shuffled_points.T) # in .scatter()-method order does NOT matter

plt.plot(*points.T, color="r")  # in .plot()-method interpolator follows the order
plt.plot(*shuffled_points.T, color="r") #    method creates a SEQUENCE of LINEs



Did I read correctly you "test" a trained model by nothing else but the points it was actually "trained" with? Which university course did teach this? Testing the "predictive"-powers of the "trained"-model shall expose such model with not yet seen data ( not just the same set, just in another order of appearances ), shan't it? Would you mind to improve your answer with actual results from true testing as noted in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78811505/why-does-order-of-the-data-matter-for-neural-network#comment138951451_78811868 ?

Don’t make it a big deal. The OP’s issue is with Matplotlib, not ML. Feel free to "improve" the answer ;)

Plot at least the .scatter() of actually predicted_points ...

Updated the answer by removing the prediction to meet you halfway. Can't do any better ;)

@user3666197 main goal of the AI is actually to approximate the function and draw some kind of shape, based on given points.

With all respect, not so. As documetned in source code, the "AI" was not tested in any single other point, than in those, that were "trained" ( to no surprise ) and that were "matching" the function ( so having no counter-examples, no attempt was made to see, how well or bad was the model in "generalising" a trained dataset ). The source code paints points ( in .scatter()-method ) or interpolated lines ( in .plot()-method ), yet neither the former, the less the latter was a thing emergent from AI model, only a standard output from Matplotlib, AI-model has no clue of "shape", it saw points.

@user3666197 well how should testing data should be made for points which represent some implicit function?

As was described here - https://stackoverflow.com/users/3666197/user3666197 If a trained ( 2-in-2-out )-transformer indeed covers "correct" translations over the whole such domains, you are safe it works. If it generates garbage or crashes, well better to know that before it "kills next crew" as explained above - that's fair, isn't it? Who would like to repeat any of the NASA experienced  errors any single time again? One never knows who will be the crew "(not) to be killed again", does we?

@user3666197 oh thanks for pointing out! i made a critical error i should map coordinates to the one output because by definition implicit function is such a function that F(r1, r2, r3 .... rn) = 0

Solved it, so actually problem was how i was drawing the actual result of the AI. Ai actually generalized it good but, since points were shuffled matplotlib just connected the points out of order and got weird results.

Could you prove this claim? Best by publishing the full code & also run & post the results from the "predictive"-model with a randomised order of grid-points [ x_i, y_i ]-inputs for some 1E9 test cases covering 2D-domains of ( -1E1, +1E1 ), ( -1E401, -1E400 ), ( -1E-400, +1E-400 ) to see the actual level of "correctness" the model as-is yields. Anyway, enjoy the future :o)

uh why would i include such a large values when initial function doesnt extend to that limits @user3666197

The point is to indeed validate if a "trained"-predictor does well in real world situations ( real world does not  curate "academically"-naive datasets, rather the very contrary - NASA Apollo-11 Moon-landing alarms ( were hair-close to a crash or mission scrub w denigrating flyby & return back to Earth ) was a crystal-clear example, how "academically"-naive "testing"-(only-pre-sanitised)-examples could kill the whole crew. Same here - if you gave zero examples from these domains in training ( which you did not ), the more you should responsibly test, what gets "out" if asked to .predict()...
